# Wordpress logout appends cache/all/index.php to the site_url()

Tags: plugins, php, cache

I have a wordpress website when i try to logout using custom menu logout link and redirect to home page it appends this cache/all/index.php to the site_url() like https://www.example.com/cache/all/index.php. I have two plugins installed Autoptimize & WP Fastest cache. I cleared them and even deactivated these plugins. It resulted in website design break down and looked ugly.And still the url append didn't go it was still a bug and didn't work. So i had to enable them back. How to solve this issue i am not able to find a solution.

Comment: I recommend checking with the plugin support streams for Autoptimize and WP Fastest Cache (my gut instinct would be to start with the latter).

Comment: If you disabled both plugins and STILL had the same issue, you probably have something else going on. (although, it could still be cached, even after that plugin is disabled) ...  How did you get/create the custom logout link?  Did you create it, or was it another plugin?